# Can someone tell me why am i getting this error?

Tags: c, realloc

I wrote a program that has a menu. First is double the space of the table, second minimize the space of the table by half, etc. Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void double_space(int *table, int *n);
    void half_space(int *table, int *n);
    void fill(int *table, int n, int start, int finish);

    void main()
    {
        int N = 4;
        int *t;
        int i, choice;

        t = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        if(t == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory...");
            exit(0);
        }

        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            t[i] = i;
        }

        while (1)
        {
            printf("\tMENU\n");
            printf("1) Double the size of table\n");
            printf("2) Minimize the size of table\n");
            printf("3) Print table\n");
            printf("4) Exit the program\n");
            printf("Choose one of the above: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                double_space(t, &N);
                fill(t, N, N/2, N-1);
                printf("\nTable is double in size");
                break;
            case 2:
                half_space(t, &N);
                fill(t, N, N/2, N-1);
                printf("\nTable is half in size");
                break;
            case 3:
                for (i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    printf("%d ", t[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice...");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void double_space(int *table, int *n)
    {
        *n = (*n)*2;

        table = (int *)realloc(table, *n);
        if(table == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory...");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    void half_space(int *table, int *n)
    {
        *n = (*n) / 2;

        table = (int *)realloc(table, *n);
        if(table == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory...");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    void fill(int *table, int  n, int start, int finish)
    {
        int i;

        if(start>=0 && start<=finish && finish<=n-1)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));

            for (i=start; i<=finish; i++)
            {
                table[i] = rand() % 100;
            }
        }

    }
```

After choosing the First choice and then the 3rd choice to print the table it prints the doubled size table. Then when i choose again the 1st choice it outputs this error:

```
    realloc(): invalid next size
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: You may want to move the `srand` call to the top of your program and only call it once unless you are resetting the seed on purpose.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yea i did transfer it to the start of the main function but nothing changed i still get the same error.

Comment: Do you realise that `table = (int *)realloc(table, *n);` inside functions will not find its way back to `t` in `main`? Note too, that you have not allowed for `sizeof(int)` in the `realloc` calls.

Comment: @AndreasSoteriou It wouldn't change the problem you're having, just a comment on a common mistake I see fairly often when folks ask "why are all the numbers the same?"

Comment: @WeatherVane why  table = (int *)realloc(table, *n) ; will not find it's way  back to the table in main

Comment: Because `int *table` is a *copy* of the value from `int *t` and is forgotten on function exit.. You'll need a double-star, and pass the *address* of `int *t`, OR, `return` the new pointer value and change the functions' type to `int*`.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok. thanks very much..!